# How to move Craft from a subdirectory to public_html

Tags: staging

I have my Craft 3 site all up and running on `domain.com/2/`

I need to move it to just `domain.com`

The Craft files are all one level above `public_html` like they should be. Not sure what I need to change to bring everything from /2/ to the root level. Would like to avoid installing a fresh copy of Craft if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without having seen your setup, I'd say this is what you need to do:

- Move all files and folders (don't forget the hidden ones) to the correct location
- Edit your web/index.php file, to make it look for Craft in the right location (it's looking 2 folders up now, it should only be one folder up.
- Change your site's base url, in your `config/general.php`, `.env`, or wherever you've set it.
- Change the paths and urls for the asset folders
- Just to be sure, clear your cache (removing the contents of `storage/runtime` should do the trick)

Again, depending on your setup there's a thousand things that could prevent this from working, but it should get you going!

Comment: Nice! I kept the actual Craft folder where it was, but moved the folder in the public_html up a level. Did the other edits you mentioned. Search was the only thing not working, but i rebuilt the search indexes and it seemed to fix it. Easy peezy!